# Facebook business verification required for my bot

Tags: facebook, chatbot, facebook-chatbot, facebook-app-requests

I know that Facebook changed their Policies but as I saw in the answer of the question:

[Business verification required as part of my app review](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51089608/business-verification-required-as-part-of-my-app-review)

I don't demand any information that requires Facebook Business verification that I am aware of. Or am I missing something? My bot only needs to read commands from the user and then show some results.

Where can I make changes so that my app doesn't require this Business verification?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got the answer from the Administrator of Messenger Platform Developer Community
and he said

> All apps that integrate with the Messenger Platform require business
>   verification.