# Facebook app Business Verification

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have read [Business verification required as part of my app review](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51089608/business-verification-required-as-part-of-my-app-review) but i have some more questions about the process.

My app uses the two default permissions (email, default) and Page Public Content Access, and I was wondering why i am getting the app business verification part, since I dont feel i need to verify a business for this. For ex. in the link above the person asking wanted user_friends, and in the https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/changelog it states that that permission requires both app and buisness verification. My question:

1. Why am i getting a business verification requirement? Is it because
   of  the Page Public Content Access? I cant find a full table that
   explain which permissions require both an app review and a business
   review. Or am i getting it because in the settings for the app under Business Use i
   selected that my app supports other business. My app maps events
   from the facebook pages of restaurants and clubs , so it sounded to
   be that it supports the other businesses rather than supports my own
   business.

Comment: If you are supporting other businesses and are not doing that on a pure “unpaid favor” basis, then you must have some sort of business that those other business makes their payments to, no …?

Comment: There is absolutely no money evolved, i simply have an app that marks the locations of the restaurants and clubs, i dont ask them to pay me, i dont ask users to pay for the app, nothing.

Comment: Still, PPCA would give you access to _all_ public page content on the network - so a more thorough "vetting" process is really in the interest of anyone who uses the platform.

Comment: Okay so can we conduct that the reason i am getting a Business Verification request is because of PPCA and not because of "Business use : Support Other Businesses" ? Because that is what i am trying to figure out. If its because of the bisness use i will just change my settings and submit another review.

Comment: Well just try it then, should be rather quick to figure out whether that's it or not.

Comment: @cbroe it's not so easy. Once you send the details for review they do everything before checking what you sent (we're pending the same app verification & business thing for over a month now). And their support reps are just useless, gave us bad info more multiple times

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51089608/business-verification-required-as-part-of-my-app-review