# Post to my own page using the Facebook API without business verification

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've been using the Facebook API to post automatic updates on one of the pages I own using the `pages_manage_posts` permission. At that time (around 2018), I also wanted to use the `user_friends` API, but I gave up on it since it required [business verification](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51089608/2604492).

Today I received an email that says the following:

> Your app currently has access to one or more privileges that require business verification, but this app is not currently associated with a verified business.
> If you do not associate your app with a verified business or complete business verification, the app will lose access to the following privileges in 90 days: `pages_manage_posts`

Do I understand it correctly that without a registered business, I can no longer use the API to programmatically post **on my own page**? I really hope that I'm wrong, and if I am, please tell me how to do that.

If that's relevant, I'm using PHP by following [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7833145/2604492).

Comment: Individual Verification instead of Business should do, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/development/release/individual-verification#limitations

Comment: Thanks @CBroe. My Individual Verification Status is already Verified. But still, I got the email I got. Any idea what can be done now to prevent my app from losing access to the privilege in 90 days?